# Android layout with sw600dp and sw720dp

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I want to support `600dp` screen in my android application. So i have made that layout using `layout-sw600dp`. But i cannot get the exact layout with the application.

I got `800 X 1280` screen size with `layout-sw720dp` but layout is little bit worse with `720 X 1280` size.

So what can i do to support `720 X 1280` in `layout-sw720dp` and `600 X 1024` in `layout-sw600dp` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For tablets you can just create the layout and drawable with following qualifiers

> layout-sw600dp
>   drawable-sw600dp

which means tablet screen with minimum of 600dp and higher can use this layout and drawable.

So for standard configuration qualifiers for screen size you can create following configuration:

```
1)layout-sw480dp drawable-sw480dp

2)layout-sw600dp drawable-sw600dp

3)layout-sw720dp drawable-sw720dp
```

Ref: [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
go for following
Table 2. New configuration qualifiers for screen size (introduced in Android 3.2).

Comment: drawable-sw600dp i dont think this is a valid folder for images.